# Does Spring store all properties into a single hashmap?

Tags: java, spring

**Does Spring put all properties into the same hashmap/list?**
**How can I get a list of all of the properties being managed by Spring**

For example, if I have two properties files and they define overlapping properties which

```
// FILE: src/main/resources/file1.properties
prop1.color = red
prop1.fill  = green
```

```
// FILE: src/main/resources/file2.properties
prop2.color = purple
prop1.fill  = ORANGE
```

The configuration class used to tell Spring to read the two files is something like this:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:file1.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:file2.properties")
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
}
```

**My question is Can I get an iterator to access all of the properties defined?** If so how.

### Searching for answer

So far I haven't found a solution to this question.

I did an Internet search for "stack overflow Spring properties" and did not found the answer.

Some SO questions I found are:

- [Spring boot get all properties from properties file and load into hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63469130/spring-boot-get-all-properties-from-properties-file-and-load-into-hashmap)
- [Spring Boot application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080113/spring-boot-application-properties)

But they didn't answer my question

Comment: I would imagine one overrides the other irretrievably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring provides a [`PropertySources`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySources.html) interface which is implemented by the `MutablePropertySources` class. This class basically just holds a list of [`PropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySource.html) instances (e.g. instances of the `PropertiesPropertySource` class - not to be confused with the `@PropertySource` annotation) and provides methods for iterating over these instances.

If you look at the [implementation of `MutablePropertySources`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/env/MutablePropertySources.java) you can see that there are multiple methods for adding `PropertySource` instances at different positions and relative to other `PropertySource`s in that list. If you want to get the value of a property, you can call the `get` method of a `MutablePropertySources` instance with the name of that property. The `get` method then iterates over all `PropertySource`s in its list and tries to find a property with the given name.

Then there is the `Environment` interface that is implemented by the abstract class `AbstractEnvironment`. You can use the latter to access the `PropertySources` instance that is used by that environment.

For example, for testing purposes, you can do the following to print out all properties and their values that are managed by [`MapPropertySource`s](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/MapPropertySource.html) - a subtype of `PropertySource`.

```java
@PropertySource("classpath:file1.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:file2.properties")
@Configuration
public class ExampleConfig {

    @Autowired
    public ExampleConfig(Environment environment) {
        AbstractEnvironment env = (AbstractEnvironment) environment;
        for (org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource<?> source : env.getPropertySources()) {
            if (source instanceof MapPropertySource mapPropertySource) {
                System.out.println(mapPropertySource.getSource());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can check out the [`org.springframework.core.env`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/4f8516e2c3ca420b1608840ab901bf9df7e4d5f1/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/env) package which contains all of these classes.

So, to answer your first answer more explicitly: No, Spring does not put all properties into a single map. It puts properties from different locations into different `PropertySource`s which are then added to a `PropertySources` instance.

Comment: Your answer (after I ran the code) also answered another question, namely: *Does Spring keep track of what file was used to define a property?*  The answer is **yes**.  Each property source has a separate entry in the list.  My belief (not yet tested) is that if a property is defined in multiple files, the first file found "wins".